# Case not working

Tags: php

So here is the code -

```
    $info = 0;
  switch ( $info ) {
    case ( $info < 11 ):
     $ts = "zero";
     break;
    case ( $info <= 44 && $info >= 11):
     $ts = "two";
     break;
    case ( $info > 44 ):
     $ts = "three";
     break;
   }

echo $ts;
```

It doesn't give out zero, bur it gives out "two", maybe you have an idea why? It only happens if $info = 0.

Comment: you're lucky it lets things other than int :)

Comment: Ah! Wish it were this simple... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `case` [expects a *value,*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) not a condition, and the conditions you're providing are being *converted* into values before comparison with the `switch` argument.

With `$info` being 0:

`$info < 11` is true, hence gives 1.

`$info <= 44 && $info >= 11` is false, hence gives 0.

`$info > 44` is false, hence gives 0.

So it's matching the *first* case where the `$info` value of 0 is equal to the condition converted to a number, which is the second one. That's why you're seeing `"two"`.

I would suggest changing it into an `if/else` variant:

```
if ($info < 11) {
    $ts = "zero";
} elseif ($info >= 11 && $info <= 44) {
    $ts = "two";
} elseif ($info > 44) {
    $ts = "three";
}
```

or possibly better, since it removes extraneous checks and ensures that *some* value is always assigned:

```
if ($info < 11) {
    $ts = "zero";
} elseif ($info < 45) {
    $ts = "two";
} else {
    $ts = "three";
}
```

Comment: Ohh, lol, thanks, and I was thinking, that I did something wrong ;)! Gonna use if statement.

Comment: @user1184908: well, technically, you _did_ do something wrong, but it's an honest misteak to make :-)

Answer (score 1):

- You switch on $info
- `( $info < 11 )` evaluates to true, which does not equal $info, which is 0, so this branch is not taken
- `( $info <= 44 && $info >= 11)` evaluates to false, which equals $info (false == 0), so this branch is taken

Answer (score 0):

I think `case` only supports value and not logical statements. That is, you can ask if variable equals some value...

```
switch ( $info ){
case 0:
// something
break;
case 11:
// something else
break;
default:
// otherwise
}
```

To achieve what you want, you need to use `IF-ELSE-IF` control structure

Answer (score 0):

from manual:

> The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the
>   same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same
>   variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a
>   different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is
>   exactly what the switch statement is for.

you code are equal is:

```
if($info == ($info < 11 )) {...} 
    elseif($info == ( $info <= 44 && $info >= 11)) {...} 
        elseif($info == ( $info > 44 )) {...} ...
```

but your correct code should be the:  "**switch ( *true* )**"

```
    $info = 0;
  switch ( true ) {
    case ( $info < 11 ):
     $ts = "zero";
     break;
    case ( $info <= 44 && $info >= 11):
     $ts = "two";
     break;
    case ( $info > 44 ):
     $ts = "three";
     break;
   }

echo $ts;
```

or simply:

```
    $info = 0;
  switch ( true ) {
    case ( $info < 11 ):
     $ts = "zero";
     break;
    case ( $info <= 44 ):
     $ts = "two";
     break;
    default:
     $ts = "three";
   }

echo $ts;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my switch interval function:

```
function switchi($i,&$var,$case)
{
    foreach($case as $interval => $new_val)
    {
        if(is_int($interval) and $interval == $i)return $var = $new_val;
        if(strpos($interval,"-"))
        {
            $interval_array = explode("-",$interval);
            if($interval_array[0]<=$i and $i<=$interval_array[1])return $var = $new_val;
            if($interval_array[0]<=$i and !$interval_array[1])return $var = $new_val;
        }

    }
    if(array_key_exists('default',$case))return $var = $case['default'];
}
```

usage:

```
$pieces = 6;
switchi($pieces,$multiplier,array(
        1           =>60,
        2           =>35,
        3           =>30,
        4           =>25,
        5           =>22,
        "6-8"       =>20,
        "9-10"      =>18,
        "11-20"     =>15,
        "21-30"     =>14,
        "31-40"     =>13,
        "41-50"     =>12,
        "51-100"    =>11,
        "101-200"   =>10,
        "201-300"   =>9,
        "301-400"   =>8,
        "401-"      =>7,
        "default"   => 0,
    ));
    echo $multiplier; //20
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your code in this format:

```
<?php
  $info = 0;
  //$info = 14;
  switch ( true) {
    case ( $info < 11 ):
     $ts = "zero";
     break;
    case ( $info <= 44 && $info >= 11):
     $ts = "two";
     break;
    case ( $info > 44 ):
     $ts = "three";
     break;
   }

echo $ts;
?>
```